# Unable to get Status of Checkbox from a Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to run the following function:

```
var getFavorite = function(){
var favCheck = document.querySelector("#fav");
var status;

if(favCheck.checked){
    status = "Yes!";
}else{
    status = "No";
}
return status;
};
```

The html form contains the following:

```
<form action="#" id="flavorForm">
    <ul id="errors"></ul>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="drug">Flavor: </label>
        <input type="text" name="flavor" id="flavor" class="required" />
    </div>  
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="favorite">Favorite?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="favorite" value="Yes" class="checkbox" />

    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="notes">Notes: </label>
        <textarea name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>
    </div>  
        <input type="submit" value="Save Flavor" id="submitFlavor" data-theme="b" />

</form>
```

And the values for favCheck should come from the second ... block of the form. But I'm getting a 'TypeError: favCheck is null' whenever I input a value on the form, whether I check the checkbox or not. I am using jQuery to retrieve the values. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you don't have any element with ID equal to fav...

Comment: `var getFavorite = function () {    
    return  document.getElementById("#favorite").checked;
};`

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled the id name. Please use `#favorite` instead of `#fav`

Try this,

```
var getFavorite = function(){
var favCheck = document.querySelector("#favorite");
var status;

if(favCheck.checked){
    status = "Yes!";
}else{
    status = "No";
}
return status;
};
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/UVx5c/)

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML

<input type="checkbox" id="checkme" checked="checked" />

jQuery


$('#checkme').change(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#checkme').prop('checked');
    if (checkbox) {
        alert('checkbox is checked');
    } else {
        alert('checkbox is not checked');
    }
});


http://jsfiddle.net/rjE8P/
```

Comment: The checkbox changing won't matter unless there's an event listener for it, which is not shown in the OP code.  The function he posted will get the value at the start of the page load and nothing else

Comment: @Deryck i was thinking OP already uses function getFavorite as callback of some event

Comment: @A.Wolff tis a possibility but there's nothing inline and you know what happens when we assume ;)

Comment: @Deryck ya i know ;) But clearly here, OP was using wrong ID and BTW told us he get error for null element

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an ID rather than a class

```
favcheck = document.getElementById('fav');
```

Also, you need to actually use that ID `fav` rather than `favorite` as it is now.

Comment: Those will give the same results

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#favorite').change(function(){
  var status;
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     status = 'Yes';
  }
  else{
     status = "No";
  }
  alert(status);
});
```